# How can I output multiple folders with webpack?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, webpack

I have a folder structure for my JS modules. I want one module per page. This is not a single page app.

How can I output files in a folder structure?

From what I can see, the only possibility is to output `[name].js`. This could work if I make the names very unique, or I could make the names have a `-` for a folder separator. That would mean `a/b/c.js` would translate to name `a-b-c`. I really don't like this. I would like to be able to `require("a/b/c")`.

From what I can tell, I can't use a single bundled file either because `require` is not available outside of the module. If it was, I could just build a single bundle and `require("a/b/c")` on every page.

If there is a good way to do this that I'm not finding on the internet, please let me know.

It looks like I'm able to easily do this with require.js using r.js, but I don't want to use require.js and would like CommonJS modules.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this but not quite the same. In my `webpack.config.js` I created several different configurations that I switch between depending on the NODE_ENV environment variable that I set when i run different `npm` scripts. For example, in my `package.json` I have a script called `build-dev` which runs `"set NODE_ENV=development&& webpack"`. Hope this gives you some ideas!

Answer (score 14):

You can define an entry point using slash, like this:

```
entry: {
    "main-plugin/js/background":"./src/main-plugin/background"
}
```

And `output` like this:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
```

This setup will create a `public/main-plugin/js` folder and will place the `background.js` into it. It works at least on `Win7x64`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [name] to make new folders too. Like this:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: '[name]/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little wrangling with node you can create an `entry` object to pass in the config. In my case I used the name of the folders of the second level to create different bundles, but you can easily adapt to your needs.

```
const path = require('path');
var glob = require('glob')

const exportPath = path.resolve(__dirname,`./../public/javascripts/plugins`);

// create a glob of files
const entryArray = glob.sync('./plugins/**/{svg,src}/**/*.*');

/**
 * Create a dictionary of entries in format: folder: ['file', 'file2']
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry
 */

var folders = []
var entries = {};

// list unique folders
entryArray.map((item) => {
  const folderName = item.split('/')[2];
  if (!folders.includes(folderName)) {
    folders.push(folderName);
  }
});

// assign files to each folder
folders.map((folder) => {
  var imports = [];
  entryArray.map((item) => {
    const folderName = item.split('/')[2];
    
    if (folder == folderName) {
      imports.push(item);
    }

  });

  entries[folder] = imports
});

module.exports = {
    entry: entries,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                presets: [ '@babel/preset-env' ],
              },
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [
                  require('postcss-nested-ancestors'),
                  require('postcss-nested')
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'svg-inline-loader?removeSVGTagAttrs=false'
        }
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: exportPath,
    filename: '[name]/dist/bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  }
};
```